# How do we access the dynamic values of property file into pom.Xml

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

I'm using Cucumber + testNG + Maven + extentreports -

My scenario:

I have a properties file as
test.properties

```
TestcaseID=TC001
TestcaseName=TCName1
```

The values TC001 and TCName1 are dynamic which I'm updating during runtime into my test.properties file.

Now in my pom.Xml, at runtime how do I access the value of TestcaseID and TestcaseName

I'm not sure how does this work.

Comment: 1. What do you mean when say "update properties in runtime into property file"? 2. what do you mean by accessing properties from pom?

Comment: 1) Runtime as in, I'm updating the values TC001 and TCName1 while running the script.. These 2 values depend on which Testcase I run from the test data. 2)And the same values TC001 and TCName1 I need to use it in pom.xml, so how do u get those 2values into pom. Xml